# Using Shell script and sed - Find and replace a word in file and rename file

Tags: shell, sed, shell-exec

I am writing one shell script which finds a given text in the files and replace that from a specified path and after replacing the text, Rename that file with with the given word.
I am getting an error of permission denied while using the sed. My script looks like this

```
`echo "Please Insert the path of the folder"
 read input_variable

    read -p "You entered: $input_variable is correct y/n  " yn

    read -p "Enter the word to find = " word
    read -p "Enter word to replace = " replace
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) find "${input_variable}" -type f -iname "${word}.*" | while read filename; do "`echo "${filename}" | sed -i 's/$word/$replace/g' ${filename}| sed -i 's/\$word/\$replace/' ${filename}`"; done ;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac`
```

I am getting the below error

> bulk_rename.sh: 34: bulk_rename.sh: : Permission denied

Any suggestions ?

After the suggestion by @vijay updated the script

```
echo "Please Insert the path of the folder"
read input_variable

read -p "You entered: $input_variable is correct y/n  " yn

read -p "Enter the word to find = " word
read -p "Enter word to replace = " replace
case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) find "${input_variable}" -type f -iname "${word}.*" | while read filename; do 
    perl -pi -e 's/$word/$replace' ${filename}
    mv ${filename} $word;   done;;

    [Nn]* ) exit;;
    * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
esac
```

now I am getting the following

---

> Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1

This is what i get when I chmod and displays the output

```
abc@PC-DEV-41717:~/Documents/blog$ chmod +x bulk_rename.sh ; /bin/ls -l bulk_rename.sh
chmod +x bulk_rename.sh ; /bin/ls -l bulk_rename.sh
+ chmod +x bulk_rename.sh
+ /bin/ls -l bulk_rename.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 abc abc 1273 Aug  1 16:51 bulk_rename.sh
```

Comment: `chmod +x bulk_rename.sh`

Comment: Maybe you don't have permissions to edit the files in question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @devnull I have tried changing the permissions as well and it is giving me same issue.

Comment: Tried what?  Check the permissions of the files that you're attempting to modify.  You don't seem to have permissions to modify those.

Comment: Updated my comment above also I have tried changing the permissions on both the script and the folder i am trying to access.

Comment: Copy the output of `set -vx; /bin/ls -l bulk_rename.sh; chmod +x bulk_rename.sh ; /bin/ls -l bulk_rename.sh` into you question above. Use the `{}` code tool at the top of the input box to keep the formatting. Maybe then we can help. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I have updated the question as told by you and my input box is taking the value as have tried echoing the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I come with my solution of my problem using the SED and with the help of this question that I have asked [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080424/shell-change-file-name-without-changing-extension-from-a-given-path/18080677?noredirect=1#comment26470680_18080677)

```
echo "Please Insert the path of the folder"
read input_variable

read -p "You entered: $input_variable is correct y/n  " yn

read -p "Enter the word to find = " word
read -p "Enter word to replace = " replace
case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) grep -r -l "$word" $input_variable  | while read file; do echo $file; echo $fname; sed -i "s/\<$word\>/$replace/g" $file ; done; find "$input_variable" -type f -name "$word.*" | while read file; do dir=${file%/*};  base=${file##*/}; noext=${base%.*}; ext=${base:${#noext}}; newname=${noext/"$word"/"$replace"}$ext; echo mv "$file" "$dir/$newname"; done;;
    [Nn]* ) exit;;
    * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are making it complex:
why not make it simple with two simple satements. Its up to you how you use the below statements for your purpose:

```
perl -pi -e 's/wordtofind/wordtoreplace' your_file #for replacing the word in the file

mv your_file wordtoreplace  #for renaming the file
```

Comment: Thanks @Vijay.. I am new with shell scripting . I will be having a list of files in which I'll be editing. So what you recommend is my above script is correct as I am prompting everything from user. And how sed is different from this.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
   perl -pi -e 's/$word/$replace' ${filename}
```

To

```
   perl -pi -e "s/$word/$replace/" ${filename}
 --------------^----------------^^--------
```

The error msg indicates a missing `/' char.

---

Also, so what error do you know get with your original code?

Note that the you'll need dbl-quotes surrounding your sed, just as in perl, so the shell can substitute in the values. i.e.

```
..... | sed -i "s/$word/$replace/g"
     ----------^------------------^
```

This assumes there are not naughty characters, especially `/` inside of `$word` or `$replace`.

IHTH