# Shell - Change file name without changing extension from a given path

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a script where I am iterating through a folder and renaming a file without changing the extension from a given path. I am getting path of the file using find -for example

> abc/xyz/qwe.txt

Now I am accepting the file name from the user and want to rename the file like

> abc/xyz/myfile.txt

What can be solution for this. How can I rename the file ? I have tried below code

```
find "$input_variable" -type f -name $word.* | while read file; do  mv $file | sed "s/$word/$replace/"; done;;
```

**Update**
Trying this

```
echo "Please Insert the path of the folder"
read input_variable

read -p "Enter the word to find = " word
read -p "Enter word to replace = " replace

find "$input_variable" -type f -name "$word.*" | while read file; 
do
    echo "$file"
    s="$file"
    d="`dirname $s`"
    f="`basename $s`"
    nf=$(echo $f | sed "s/^[^.]*\./$word./")
    newFileName="$d/$nf"
done
```

Comment: Surround your echo .. | sed .. in `$(...)`.

Comment: and add a `do` at the beginning of your `while`-loop

Comment: @umläute my bad was a typo updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one way:

```
find "$input_variable" -type f -name "$word.*" | while read file; do
    dir=${file%/*}
    base=${file##*/}
    ext=${base##*.}
    noext=${base:0:${#base} - ${#ext} - 1}
    newname=${noext/"$word"/"$replace"}.$ext
    echo mv "$file" "$dir/$newname"
done
```

Remove the echo part when you're sure it's already correct.

Edit:

```
find "$input_variable" -type f -name "$word.*" | while read file; do
    dir=${file%/*}
    base=${file##*/}
    noext=${base%.*}
    ext=${base:${#noext}}
    newname=${noext/"$word"/"$replace"}$ext
    echo mv "$file" "$dir/$newname"
done
```

Comment: #konsolebox thanks for reply.Using your code getting an error of bad substitution.

Comment: @ArihantGodha I would guess that you're not using bash. What shell are you using?

Comment: in noext=${base:0:${#base} - ${#ext} - 1}

Comment: PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3876 pts/0    00:00:00 bash

Comment: The script needs modification and won't work on filenames with no extensions but if you have -name '<any>.*' in your find command it should work. e.g. -name '*.*'

Comment: @ArihantGodha I updated the script. It should work with any filename now.

Comment: still giving bad substitution

Comment: @ArihantGodha Can you give me the exact command you're running? Can you place it in a script instead? What version of bash (bash --version)? Also, please make sure you're running the exact intended find command.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu). I am executing my program using sh myprogram.sh command

Comment: Pleaes try to execute it using bash myprogram.sh instead. And make sure it's the updated version.

Comment: Which version should I try with ?

Comment: The second I posted above. After Edit:.

Comment: Finally it worked. :) Used bash filename.sh to run. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

**Updating it again as OP seems to be using some old shell:**

Use [**dirname**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) and [**basename**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename):

```
s="abc/xyz/myfile.txt"
d="`dirname $s`"
f="`basename $s`"

mf="myfile"
nf=`echo $f | sed "s/^[^.]*\./$mf./"`
# merge the dir name and new file name
newFileName="$d/$nf"
```

**TESTING:**

```
$ echo "$newFileName"
abc/xyz/myfile.txt
```

Comment: can i pass a variable in place of myfile. I have tried nf=$(sed 's/^[^.]*\./"$word"./' <<< $f) getting redirection unexpected
.

Comment: thanks for replying but getting redirection unexpected here nf=$(sed 's/^[^.]*\./$word./' <<< $f)

Comment: Made another edit to remove `<<<` and use simple pipe, try it now.

Comment: It seems you're using some old shell. Edited it again, try now. Also tell what you see when you do `echo $SHELL` You can put all those commands in a file and call it like `bash c "script.sh"`

Comment: echo $SHELL output = /bin/bash my bash version is GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Any of 2 answers should work for you on bash. Anyway did you try my latest edited code?

Comment: Please check I have updated the question. Can you please try that at your end. I am using Linux just if that helps in relation of environment.